#  [warning] 'Player' moved wrongly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm getting this warning from my server console (and just happens to be for the same player each time). I'm the only mod of the server so I know no one is using commands to teleport themselves and even if they did it would leave a log. What causes this warning?

Comment: Is this a vanilla or Bukkit server?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Vanilla. The one you download from the main site

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This warning is generated every time a player moved to a position or at a speed which the server thinks is impossible. This can happen spuriously, as the assumptions the server makes aren't quite the same as what you can actually do (the server doesn't analyze the player's exact inputs), or it can happen due to an attempted cheat, or due to the world changing as the player attempts to pass through it (e.g. player moves through a block the server knows about but the client hasn't seen yet due to latency).

Whenever this happens the server sends a message to the client resetting the player’s position to the last valid one (this can be noticed from that player’s perspective as a sudden shift).

Comment: Cheers, I discovered he was using a flying mod.

Comment: This happens to people in my server often when they walk near the corner of a chest. From the players perspective it looks like the player gets 'stuck' unable to move forward and unable to rotate the mouse (the view furiously jumps back to the last rotation 20 times per second). Only stopping to move forward and going sideways or back will get you unstuck.

Answer (score 5):

It usually means the player in question is flying, as the server is not expecting the movements flying creates.

Answer (score 2):

This means that a player moved faster or farther than possible without the use of mods.

Comment: If possible, please aim for answers that are longer than one or two one-liners. :)

Comment: Sometimes simple is better, but ok.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, and sometimes the one liner is, after all, all there is to say about a topic. I feel some of your answers could have been improved by adding a few extra details, and it seems the voting on your answers mostly reflects this. :) (by the way - welcome!)

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for the one-liners, I'll try to expound on my answers more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It means that, from the perspective of the server, someone did something that *should* be impossible.

This usually means flying or falling into the void.