# "Player moved wrongly" not involving cheats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In [this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46993/warning-player-moved-wrongly), the answers assumed (correctly, as it turned out) that the player in question was using cheats.

I'm frequently seeing "[Player] moved wrongly!" and "Horse moved wrongly!" for all the players on my server, including myself, and I'm not using any cheats.  What else could cause this?

**Edit:** The server is running in Linux on an i7-3770 and never using more than about 7% of its allocated 1 GB RAM.  I'm not sure how to tell or configure how many cores it's allowed to use.  I'm playing locally, so the network performance should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this too on a server with not that much performance. As soon as I replaced it with one that had way better specs, I got rid of those messages. Your server is probably to slow to process all the Client-Requests (the faster you move, the more Junks the server will need to send you).
Try flying around with the "Elytra". You will probably lag so much that it's not funny to do it.

A painfull fix could be to lower your "view-distance" in your "server.properties" file.

Comment: I added some information about the server hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This can caused if a player glitches to a block with little lag.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by server lagg, or client lag.
Upgrade your server or get the server on a better internet connection

Comment: I added some information about the server hardware.